Question about a proof
Corollary 7.9. Let a function  $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$  be integrable with respect to a Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure  $\mu$ . Then for any  $\varepsilon>0$, there is a continuous function  g  which vanishes outside a finite interval such that
$\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f-g| d \mu<\varepsilon $.
Proof. It suffices to prove the claim for real functions f. Fix  $\varepsilon>0$  and let  $\phi=\sum_{j=1}^{N} a_{j} 1_{E_{j}}$  be a simple function from the previous proposition such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f-\phi| d \mu<\varepsilon / 3$.
Let  $M:=\max _{j=1, \ldots, n}\left|a_{j}\right|$  be the supremum of  $|\phi|$ . For each  $j$, there is a compact set  $F_{j} \subseteq E_{j}$  with
$\mu\left(E_{j} \backslash F_{j}\right)<\varepsilon /(3 M N)$ .
Now we define the simple function  $\psi=\sum_{j=1}^{N} a_{j} 1_{F_{j}}$ ; then
$\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\phi-\psi| d \mu=\sum_{j=1}^{N} \mu\left(E_{j} \backslash F_{j}\right)\left|a_{j}\right| \leqslant N M \cdot \varepsilon /(3 M N)=\varepsilon / 3$
Let  $V>0$  be such that  $\bigsqcup_{j=1}^{N} F_{j} \subseteq[-V, V]$  and set  $F_{0}=\{-V-1, V+1\}$ . We construct  $g:[-V-1, V+1] \rightarrow[-M, M]$  by starting with  $g(x)=a_{j}$  for  $x \in F_{j}$  and  $g(-V-1)=   g(V+1)=0$ .
Now the set
$U=[-V-1, V+1] \backslash \bigsqcup_{j=0}^{N} F_{j}$
is open and thus can be written as  $\bigsqcup_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(a_{k}, b_{k}\right)$ . Note that we have already defined  $g$  at all the points  $a_{k}, b_{k}, k \geqslant 1$. Then we can define  $g$  on each interval  $\left(a_{k}, b_{k}\right)$  in such a way that it will be piecewise linear, continuous on  $\left[a_{k}, b_{k}\right]$  and $\int_{a_{k}}^{b_{k}}|g-\psi| d \mu<(\varepsilon / 3) \cdot 2^{-k}$
Finally, define  $g(x)=0$  for  $|x| \geqslant V+1$ . Then  g  is continuous function on the real line, and, since  $g(x)=\psi(x)$  for  $x \notin U$ ,
$\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\psi-g| d \mu=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_{a_{k}}^{b_{k}}|g-\psi| d \mu<\varepsilon / 3$.
Question: Since $g$ is not zero on $a_k,b_k$, but $\phi = 0 \ $when $x\in (a_k,b_k)$. I don't know how to ensure the setting "Then we can define  $g$  on each interval  $\left(a_{k}, b_{k}\right)$  in such a way that it will be piecewise linear, continuous on  $\left[a_{k}, b_{k}\right]$  and $\int_{a_{k}}^{b_{k}}|g-\psi| d \mu<(\varepsilon / 3) \cdot 2^{-k}$ " is true.

First, the author should be slapped for using $a_i$ to represent both the values of $\phi$ and endpoints of the intervals in $U$. There are so many other variables available. Why make $a$ pull double-shifts while the others laze around, unwanted? (Unless in the source one of them is actually $\alpha$, in which case, a look of minor annoyance for using such similar-looking variables is sufficient.)

Now you have an interval $[a_k, b_k]$ on which $g$ is currently only defined at $a_k$ and $b_k$. Simply connect these two known points with a line segment. This makes $g$ continuous on that interval. As to why this combined with the definition of $g$ on the $F_j$ makes $g$ continuous everywhere, that will depend on that mysterious previous proposition, in particular on what is says about these sets $E_j$. If all it said was that they are measurable, then I could provide a counter-example.
